# How can you tell where an assembly function ends?

Tags: assembly, static-analysis

Finding the start of a function is sometimes obvious - for example if some part of the code has a `call foo` then `foo` must be a function.

But what about finding the end of a function? I realize tools like Radare and Ghidra do this, but it seems like they must be using heuristics because some things that "look like" the end of a function aren't. For example (in pseudo-asm):

```
foo:
  sub r1,r2
  jge something
  ret
something:
  add r1,r2
  ret
```

I would say this is one function that happens to have two different exit points, but how would a RE tool figure this out?

Comment: Decompilers perform structural analysis usually by constructing control flow graph and then the program's AST. I can recommend [No More Gotos](https://net.cs.uni-bonn.de/fileadmin/ag/martini/Staff/yakdan/dream_ndss2015.pdf) paper which shows the steps a decompiler takes to recover structured code (and how you can apply optimizations to the process), [DREAM's codebase](https://github.com/CodeIntelligenceTesting/dream) is also open source

Comment: Thanks for sharing that paper, I'm reading it now. The gist seems to match something I've been thinking about for a while - that if you can successfully decompile obfuscated code just enough to apply some optimizations, you should be able to generate something much less obfuscated.

Comment: check first 3 pages of this great resource - https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/3033019.3033028

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no definitive way to tell what instructions correspond to a single function, i.e. what exactly represents a function when looking only at the set of instructions. Compilers are free to optimize the high level code in any way they like. For reference, you can see the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25880860) provided here.

Luckily, compilers usually output predictable patterns, so Ghidra, Radare and other disassemblers first locate what they believe is a function by pattern matching and analysis of other functions, then analyze the control flow of the instructions to establish the control flow graph of the function and determine which branches the function has, where it "ends" etc.

There is also some good information here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41622226/assembly-function-recognition